# Block select unequal lines

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

I often have code of the form:

```
    money = double(123)
    user_level = user["level"]
    timer = get_time()
```

and want to have:

```
    money = double(123)
    user_level = user["level"]
    timer = get_time()

    print(money)
    print(user_level)
    print(timer)
```

How can I go from the first to the second?

My first thought was to:

1. move cursor to the "m" of "money"
2. enter visual block mode with `^v`
3. select multiple lines with `3j`
4. move to first word with `w`
5. yank with `y`
6. paste with `p`
7. use visual block mode to add `print(` prefix and `)` suffix

However, "move to first word with `w`" is not per-line and results in a rectangular block (unwanted):

```
money
user_
timer
```

Comment: Your two recent questions indicate you want to use the `:substitute` command but you're not too familiar with it. Maybe time to read `:help :substitute` and `:help pattern`?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, with visual block selection one operates on rectangular block of text.

If it was aligned on `=` you would be able to do it, otherwise you can use suggested in other answers methods.

Similar one might be using `:normal` command without macro recording:

1. Duplicate with `yap`, `Go<ESC>p`
2. Select duplicated with `vip`
3. Convert using `:norm Iprint(^[f DA)` where `^[` is generated by pressing `CTRL-V Escape`

[image: asciicast]

PS, I personally would just duplicated and manually edited the text if it is less than 5 lines.

Comment: Upvoted for the PS. For a few lines, typing it out is faster than to come up with a clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- Duplicate the lines first
- On the first line I would run the following substitution:

  `:s/\v(\S+).*/print(\1)`
- I would repeat it using the `&` key on the other lines

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Duplicate the line first
- Apply the following macro `0Iprint(^[eld$a)^[`

  - `0` go to the start of the line
    (when you run a macro on many lines it is a good practice not to assume anything about the initial position of the cursor)
  - `I` goes in edit mode to the first non white character
  - `print(` insert the initial `print(`
  - `^[` or <kbd>Esc</kbd> switch to Normal mode
  - `eld$` delete the rest of the line
  - `a)` insert the final `)`
  - `^[` or <kbd>Esc</kbd> switch to Normal mode
    (when you run a macro on many line it is a good practice to comeback to Normal mode at the end of the macro)

If you record it with `qa` and stop recording with `q` you can repeat it in the other lines with `@a`.

You can also select the lines you want to apply the macro and run:

```
:'<,'>norm @a
```

Another technique to repeat the macro is to make the macro goes to the next line: `0Iprint(^[eld$a)^[j` (notice the additional `j` at the end)

Then to run it on 2 lines you can do `2@a`.

Comment: This is the way I imagine Drew Neill, who wrote "Practical Vim", would solve this problem.